# Send post array via yii2 Html a()

Tags: php, html, object, post, yii2

When i'm trying to send array User via Yii Html a

```
echo Html::a('Text',
    ['/user/admin/create'], [
        'data' => [
            'method' => 'post',
            'params' => [
                'User' => [
                 'name' => 'qwe',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ])
```

I'm getting

```
$_POST['User'] = '[object Object]'
```

yes it's STRING!

help please

Comment: Either serialize the data to send it like that or use ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to pass an array you may use following construction:

```
<?= Html::a('Link Text', ['/user/admin/create'], [
    'data'=>[
        'method' => 'post',
        'params'=>[
            'User[name]' => 'John',
            'User[age]' => '25',
        ],
    ]
]) ?>
```

Also you can define onclick property for link and pass you own javascript handler for request.